# How to create, update and upsert leads with php toolkit using all or none header?

Tags: php, wsdl

For Java, I found an example [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_allornoneheader.htm), but I can't find any example using PHP Toolkit and I have any idea of how to do it. I have checked SforceBaseClient.php and the WSDL file. Inside WSDL file I've found some headers but on the PHP file I can only find the function setMruHeader() but there is no all or none header function. Here you have two headers that are inside my WSDL:

```
<element name="AllOrNoneHeader">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="allOrNone" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>

<element name="MruHeader">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="updateMru" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

Any idea of how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I can't because I don't work for the same company. Sorry!